# JSON_ARRAY_APPEND() reject if target value is null Mysql

Tags: mysql, json, select, mysql-json

Here is Scenario, Adding the user-id's to the `user_details`.  what if `external_id` does not present in the profile table and it returns `null` (select statement returns `null`).

How does `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND` reject the query and does not add to the `user_details` JSON colum.

```
UPDATE column1 SET user_details= JSON_SET(user_details, "$.ids", IFNULL(user_details->'$.ids',JSON_ARRAY())),
user_details= JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(user_details, "$.ids", (Select id from column2 where external_id='999999999999999'))
where id = 880;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for this in the `WHERE` clause of the `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE column1 SET user_details= JSON_SET(user_details, "$.ids", IFNULL(user_details->'$.ids',JSON_ARRAY())),
user_details= JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(user_details, "$.ids", (Select id from column2 where external_id='999999999999999'))
where id = 880
AND EXISTS (Select id from column2 where external_id='999999999999999')
```

Or use a `JOIN` rather than nesting a subquery.

```
UPDATE column1 AS c1
CROSS JOIN column2 AS c2
SET user_details= JSON_SET(c1.user_details, "$.ids", IFNULL(c1.user_details->'$.ids',JSON_ARRAY())),
    c1.user_details= JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(c1.user_details, "$.ids",c2.id)
WHERE c1..id = 880
AND c2.external_id = '999999999999999'
```